# Override path to binary for particular user

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, path

My question seems to be trivial but I didn't manage to find anything helpful in internet.
I have a binary in

```
/urs/bin/binary
```

but it is outdated and newer version is available on some mount for example

```
/mount/new_version/binary
```

An there's a bash script that invokes this binary in a form like

```
binary -doSomething
```

I need this script to invoke new version of binary instead of old one but I'm not permissioned to change this script. Is is a way to somehow override path to it but only for my user?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are not allowed to do it, talk to your admin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the binary is in `/usr/bin/binary` and the script invokes the binary without specifying the full path, but instead relies on `/usr/bin` being in `PATH` then you can simply add the location of the new binary to the beginning of the user's `PATH`. Put something like this in their `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH=/mount/new_version:$PATH
```

For security reasons, scripts often specify the full path to binaries to prevent this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the binary you can backup it and create a symbolic link.

```
mv /urs/bin/binary /urs/bin/binary.bkp
ln -s /mount/new_version/binary /urs/bin/binary
```

*[EDIT]*

Sorry, didn't saw the change must be done for one user only.

You can create a function to be called instead of the binary.

Depending on how you execute the binary (full path or just name) you must create a **suitable function**, like:

```
# Full path
function /urs/bin/binary () { command /mount/new_version/binary "$@"; }
export -f /urs/bin/binary
# Name
function binary () { command /mount/new_version/binary "$@"; }
export -f binary
```

If the binary don't accept/need arguments, remove the *"$@"*.

To automatize the function creation, put the function lines in the .profile file in the user home directory.

Comment: This will affect all users. It's not acceptable.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the answer as the change must affect one user only.

Answer (score 3):

`alias commandname=/mount/new_version/binary`

in the .bashrc above the path statement/export
or in the profile will accomplish easy enough.